# How to create object of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create the object of list that looks like this:

```
myObj = {"foo":[1,2,3,4], 
         "bar":[3,5,7,8]}
```

I tried this but failed

```
var myObj = new Object();
myObj["foo"].push(1)
myObj["foo"].push(2)
#...etc
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: You have to initialize your object's properties as array before they've got the push method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the array first

```
myObj["foo"] = []
```

then call your push method

Answer (score 0):

It depends, are you trying to reassign the `myObj` attribute `foo` with a completely new `array`? Or are you trying to append to the already existing `array`?

In the former case:

```
myObj.foo = [1,5,6,4] // new array
```

And in the latter:

```
myObj.foo.concat(/*new numbers*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` notation is commonly used.

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.foo = [];
myObj.bar = [];
```

Later you can manipulate the arrays.

```
myObj.bar.push('elem1');
myObj.bar.pop();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should declare the properties of the object as array in order not to get some unpleasent situations.So you can use new Object to create an object like this.

```
var myObj=new Object;
```

and define properties as empty arrays

```
myobj.prop1=[];
myObj.prop2=[];
```

then you can push whatever you want into prop1 or prop2 by simply reaching them inside the object as

```
myObj.prop1.push(someData)
```

OR

You can use a better way to declare this object like below

```
var myObj={
  prop1:[],
  prop2:[]
}
```

And again you can push whatever you like into them as i told above 
as myObj.prop1.push(data)

Answer (score 0):

Try first declare your object, so your second line goes first

`var myObj = new Object();`

then you fill your object with data

`myObj = {"foo":[1,2,3,4],"bar":[3,5,7,8]}`

then the rest of your code should work fine

`myObj["foo"].push(1)
 myObj["foo"].push(2)`

result `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2 ]`